# Kafka and akka (scala): How to create Source[CommittableMessage[Array[Byte], String], Consumer.Control]?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka

I would like for unit test to create a source with committable message and with Consumer control.

Or to transform a source created like this :

```
val message: Source[Array[Byte], NotUsed] = Source.single("one message".getBytes)
```

to something like this

```
Source[CommittableMessage[Array[Byte], String], Consumer.Control]
```

Goal is to unit test actor behavior on message without having to install kafka on the build machine

Answer (score 1):

You can use this helper to create a CommittableMessage:

```
package akka.kafka.internal

import akka.Done
import akka.kafka.ConsumerMessage.{CommittableMessage, CommittableOffsetBatch, GroupTopicPartition, PartitionOffset}
import akka.kafka.internal.ConsumerStage.Committer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord

import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.concurrent.Future

object AkkaKafkaHelper {

  private val committer = new Committer {
    def commit(offsets: immutable.Seq[PartitionOffset]): Future[Done] = Future.successful(Done)
    def commit(batch: CommittableOffsetBatch): Future[Done] = Future.successful(Done)
  }

  def commitableMessage[K, V](key: K, value: V, topic: String = "topic", partition: Int = 0, offset: Int = 0, groupId: String = "group"): CommittableMessage[K, V] = {
    val partitionOffset = PartitionOffset(GroupTopicPartition(groupId, topic, partition), offset)
    val record = new ConsumerRecord(topic, partition, offset, key, value)
    CommittableMessage(record, ConsumerStage.CommittableOffsetImpl(partitionOffset)(committer))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Consumer.committableSource`](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/v0.19/core/src/main/scala/akka/kafka/scaladsl/Consumer.scala#L79) to create a `Source[CommittableMessage[K, V], Control]`. The idea is that in your test you would produce one or more messages onto some topic, then use `committableSource` to consume from that same topic.

The following is an example that illustrates this approach: it's a slightly adjusted excerpt from the [`IntegrationSpec`](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka/blob/v0.19/core/src/test/scala/akka/kafka/scaladsl/IntegrationSpec.scala) in the Akka Streams Kafka project. `IntegrationSpec` uses [scalatest-embedded-kafka](https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka), which provides an in-memory Kafka instance for ScalaTest specs.

```
Source(1 to 100)
    .map(n => new ProducerRecord(topic1, partition0, null: Array[Byte], n.toString))
    .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))

val consumerSettings = createConsumerSettings(group1)

val (control, probe1) = Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, TopicSubscription(Set(topic1)))
  .filterNot(_.record.value == InitialMsg)
  .mapAsync(10) { elem =>
    elem.committableOffset.commitScaladsl().map { _ => Done }
  }
  .toMat(TestSink.probe)(Keep.both)
  .run()

probe1
  .request(25)
  .expectNextN(25).toSet should be(Set(Done))

probe1.cancel()
Await.result(control.isShutdown, remainingOrDefault)
```